# Rails: How to call one-to-one relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm new to rails and I want to know how to fetch a one-to-one relationship. I want to fetch users city. In my postgresql database I have:

```
cities Table: 

city:varchar
zipcode: integer

users Table

name:varchar 
city_id:int
```

and in city and user model I have:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :city

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

I tried the following in my search controller but didnt work, when logged in:

```
current_user.city
```

I get the following error

```
Processing by SearchController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "q"=>"", "criteria"=>"1", "commit"=>"Search"}
  User Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cities.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."user_id" =...
                                                ^
: SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column cities.user_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."user_id" =...
                                                ^
: SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities"  WHERE "cities"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1):
```

why am I suppose to add a user_id column to cities table, when I have cities foreign key in users table? I dont want to add user_id into cities table.

Comment: because I only want it to have a zipcode and city in the cities table. Then I want active record to fetch me this city object for my user

Comment: [according rails guides for has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) `This association indicates that each instance of a model contains or possesses one instance of another model.` So your user has only one cities? or you mean many to many association?([where many users can have many cities?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)) i think you search [`has_one :through Association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association)

Comment: yes 1 user has 1 city as you can see in my mapping

Comment: and exactly this city can be in other user?

Comment: oh now i see the problem :D....of course cities can have many users, sorry

Comment: so you need `has_one :through association`. join table keeps `user_id` and `city_id` for both records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`has_one :through association`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-through-association) with join table. Some example for you below.

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :city, through: :user_city
  has_one :user_city
end
```

city model:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user city join model:

```
class UserCity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :user
end
```

migration for join tables:

```
class JoinUserCity < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :user_cities do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :city_id
    end
  end
end
```

Test in rails console:

```
=> u = User.create
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-12-07 15:47:14.595728"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-07 15:47:14.595728"]]
  (3.3ms)  commit transaction
=> #<User id: 4, created_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:14", updated_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:14">
=> u.city
  City Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" INNER JOIN "user_cities" ON "cities"."id" = "user_cities"."city_id" WHERE "user_cities"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 4]]
=> nil
=> c = City.create
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "cities" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-12-07 15:47:24.535039"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-07 15:47:24.535039"]]
  (3.3ms)  commit transaction
=> #<City id: 1, created_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:24", updated_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:24">
irb(main):004:0> u.city = c
  UserCity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "user_cities".* FROM "user_cities"  WHERE "user_cities"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 4]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "user_cities" ("city_id", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["city_id", 1], ["user_id", 4]]
   (1.0ms)  commit transaction
=> #<City id: 1, created_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:24", updated_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:24">
irb(main):005:0> u.save
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
=> true
=> u = User.last
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 4, created_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:14", updated_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:14">
=> u.city
  City Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "cities".* FROM "cities" INNER JOIN "user_cities" ON "cities"."id" = "user_cities"."city_id" WHERE "user_cities"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 4]]
=> #<City id: 1, created_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:24", updated_at: "2014-12-07 15:47:24">
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the document of has_one and belogns_to,

```
belongs_to(name, options = {})
Specifies a one-to-one association with another class. This method should only be used if this class    
contains the foreign key. If the other class contains the foreign key, then you should use has_one  
instead.
```

as the user table has the foreign key, you should change your model definition like this

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end
```